# Return everything except last word from a string in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column "name" that contain first and last names. Some entries have 3 or 4 first names. Examples of names are:

```
         "Max Mustermann" 
         "Max Christian Mustermann"  
         "Max Christian von Mustermann"
```

I need to split those names into two seperate columns "firstname" and "lastname".
last name I get with the following statement I found on stack overflow:

```
UPDATE table SET 
lastname = regexp_replace(name, '^.* ', '')
```

For the first name I need to return everything except that?
At the moment I'm trying to read into the regexp_replace function but I find it hard to understand. I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the regex to cut everything after the last space inclusively:

```sql
update my_table set
    firstname = regexp_replace(name, '(^.*) .*', '\1'),
    lastname = regexp_replace(name, '^.* ', '')
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3c8cf6fc19fe2bd6566b2accd337901a)

Comment: When I tried that, first I got an error message. pgadmin told me to put an E before the '\1' statement. After adding the E I got no error message but also nothing has changed.

Comment: Most likely you made a typo, the query is correct as you can see in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [SUBSTRING](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-substring/) with a regex pattern.

> ```
> update your_table
> set first_name = substring(name, '^(\w+)')
>   , last_name  = substring(name, '^\w+\s+(.*)$')
> where (first_name is null or last_name is null);
> ```

> ```
> select name, first_name, last_name
> from your_table;
> ```

> | name | first_name | last_name |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Max Mustermann | Max | Mustermann |
> | Max Christian Mustermann | Max | Christian Mustermann |
> | Max Christian von Mustermann | Max | Christian von Mustermann |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0e6f677c36aa7248719cd488bec54bc1)*

Comment: When I tried that, first I got an error message. pgadmin told me to put an E before the '(\w+)' statement. After adding the E I got null values in most lines. For some lines the query wrote a 'w'.

Comment: Are you perhaps running the sql from a programming language where you need to escape the backslashes? `'\w+' ` versus `'\\w+'`

Answer (score 0):

Using string operators *left/right* you could do:

```
select left(names, length(names)-pos) firstname, right(names,pos-1) Surname
from t,
lateral (values(strpos(reverse(names), ' ')))v(pos);
```

[example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d52708aac6c0dd901ca21034103d88b7)

Answer (score -1):

Are you considering `split_part`?

```
UPDATE my_table SET 
firstname = split_part(name, ' ', 1), lastname = split_part(name, ' ', 2)
```

Test it in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f1a41e7a9e5ffa0d7938de46c27b9c90)